# Spring, problem with @Value in bean constructor with prototype scope

Tags: java, spring

```
cfg c= context.getBean(cfg.class);
```

First time it has to be work, but second time appear error:

> No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at
> least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations: {}

Why?

```
@Configuration
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class cfg{
    public cfg(@Value("${xx}") String xx) {
        System.out.println(xx);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
xx = 7
```

Also I found that if replace @Configuration with @Component or add (proxyBeanMethods = false) the problem goes away.

[Source code](https://github.com/tnikolai2/demo2)

Comment: Since all the classes are in a single file that isn't very long I think you should include the whole thing as part of the question (instead of posting a link to the repo).  This will also help others in the future when your repo no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

`@Configuration` indicates that a class declares one or more `@Bean` methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime. If you want `@Value` to work you will need `@PropertySource` annotation.

If you annotate it with `@Component`, then it will be a fully-fledged Spring Bean on which `@Value` works out of the box.